# Window function in MySQL queries

Tags: mysql, postgresql, window-functions

Is there a way to use window functions in MySQL queries dynamically within a SELECT query itself? (I know for a fact that it is possible in PostgreSQL).

For example, here is the equivalent query in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT c_server_ip, c_client_ip, sum(a_num_bytes_sent) OVER 
   (PARTITION BY c_server_ip) FROM network_table;
```

However, what would be the corresponding query in MySQL?

Comment: MySQL doesn't support window functions. Either use subqueries like below or mysql variables.

Comment: Those aren't "partitions". The concept of "partitioning" refers to physically *storing* rows of a table in different areas on the hard disk based on a (partitioning) key. What you are looking for is called a "window function" and MySQL does not support that (and many other modern SQL features)

Comment: @PriiduNeemre during your edit marathon you could also fix incorrect concepts instead of just trying to pretty-print each and every question that refers to Postgres on this site

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I would gladly do so if it weren't for the "This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post." option in the edit approval/rejection dialog :). That's how I earned half of the rejected edits that I have to my name so far (which is why I have effectively limited myself to improving the general readability of various questions rather than revising their contents & concepts :P).

Answer (score 3):

Starting MySQL 8.0, you can now use OVER and partition, so consider upgrading to the latest version :)

Answer (score 2):

Hope this might work:

```
select A.c_server_ip, A.c_client_ip, B.mySum
 from network_table A, (
  select c_server_ip, sum(a_num_bytes_sent) as mySum
  from network_table group by c_server_ip
 ) as B
where A.c_server_ip=B.c_server_ip;
```