# Sum of all rows prior to (and including) date on current row in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, cumulative-sum

It's important to know that the date will be unknown during the query time, so I cannot just hard code a 'WHERE' clause.

Here's my table:

```
+-----------+----------+-------------+
| Date_ID   | Customer | Order_Count |
+-----------+----------+-------------+
| 20150101  | Jones    | 6           |
| 20150102  | Jones    | 4           |
| 20150103  | Jones    | 3           |
+-----------+----------+-------------+
```

Here's the desired output:

```
+-----------+----------+------------------+
| Date_ID   | Customer | SUM(Order_Count) |
+-----------+----------+------------------+
| 20150101  | Jones    | 6                |
| 20150102  | Jones    | 10               |
| 20150103  | Jones    | 13               |
+-----------+----------+------------------+
```

My guess is I need to use a variable or perhaps a join.

Edit: still not able to get it fast enough. very slow.

Comment: Given your input data I can't see how you expect to get to your desired output.

Comment: How large is your dataset and what indexes do you have on the table?

Comment: Your desired output is pretty easy for any RDBMS that isn't MySQL, as window functions aren't supported. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720073/window-function-in-mysql-queries.

Answer (score 4):

Try this query; it's most likely the best you can do without limiting the dataset you operate on. It should benefit from an index (customer, date_id).

```
select 
  t1.date_id, t1.customer, sum(t2.order_count)
from 
  table1 t1
left join 
  table1 t2 on t1.customer = t2.customer
           and t1.date_id >= t2.date_id
group by 
  t1.date_id, t1.customer;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a0b24/5).

Answer (score 2):

One way you could go about it is by using a sub query which sums all orders up till the current order. Probably not the fastest way, but it should do the trick.

```
SELECT `Date_ID`, `Customer`, 
    (SELECT sum(b.`Order_Count`) 
    FROM tablename as b WHERE 
    b.`Date_ID` <= a.`Date_ID` AND
    a.`customer = b.`Customer`) 
FROM tablename as a
```

Comment: I have a large dataset, and the subquery is super slow. Also I think I needed a group by clause in your example, as there are actually different Customer names.

Comment: Added the customer to the subquery, but it indeed isn't very fast as it requires recalculating the full sum for each element. Indexing should help some. If it still is too slow you might want to consider calculating the sum in your program outside SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Where performance is an issue, consider a solution akin the following:

```
SELECT * FROM ints;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
+---+

SELECT i,@i:=@i+i FROM ints, (SELECT @i:=0)n ORDER BY i;
+---+----------+
| i | @i:=@i+i |
+---+----------+
| 0 |        0 |
| 1 |        1 |
| 2 |        3 |
| 3 |        6 |
| 4 |       10 |
| 5 |       15 |
| 6 |       21 |
| 7 |       28 |
| 8 |       36 |
| 9 |       45 |
+---+----------+
```

Comment: Has potential, but so far this sums all ID's regardless of the customer name...And a group by doesn't effect it either...Each customer should be summed independently.

Comment: Well I guess that's the difference between choosing to provide proper(ly representative) DDLs / an sqlfiddle, or not.

Comment: Using @ assignments in a `SELECT` is likely to be disallowed in 8.0.xx; use a "windowing" function _if_ you have 8.0 or 10.2.

Answer (score 0):

you can consider this solution
select Date_ID,
Customer,
SUM(Order_COunt) over (order by Date_ID, Customer rows unbounded preceding) as SUM(Order_COunt)
from table